# How to call function from class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to load a function value into a Literal2.Text.

I am getting the error

> ErrorArgument not specified for parameter 'LoadMenu' of 'Public
>   Function LoadMenuActivity(LoadMenu As String) As String'

I call the function on page load like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Literal2.Text = AllFunc.LoadMenuActivity

    End If
End Sub
```

Here is my Class:

Public Class AllFunc

```
Public Function LoadMenuActivity(ByVal LoadMenu As String) As String
    Dim strCON As String = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TAPVendor;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Message WHERE UserID = 'RAN' ORDER BY ID DESC"
    Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strCON)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    Dim display As String = Nothing

    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim counter As Integer = Nothing

    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        counter = counter + 1

        Dim MyString As String
        MyString = dt.Rows(i).Item("Timestamp")
        Dim MyDateTime As DateTime
        MyDateTime = New DateTime
        MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt", Nothing)

        Dim t As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - MyDateTime


        If t.TotalSeconds > 1 Then
            display = t.Seconds.ToString() + " sec ago"
        End If

        If t.TotalSeconds > 60 Then
            display = t.Minutes.ToString() + " mins ago"
        End If

        If t.TotalHours > 1 Then
            display = t.Hours.ToString() + " hrs ago"
        End If

        If t.TotalDays > 1 Then
            display = t.Days.ToString() + " days ago"
        End If

        sb.AppendFormat("<li class=""divider""></li>" &
        "   <li><a href=""#"">" &
        "<div>" &
        "<i class=""" & dt.Rows(i).Item("Icon") & """></i> " & dt.Rows(i).Item("Alert") & "" &
        "<span class=""pull-right text-muted small"">" & display & "</span></div></a></li>")
        If counter = 5 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return LoadMenu
End Function
End Class
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you are not specifying the parameter 'LoadMenu' of 'Public Function... Why don't you do so by calling it like this? `AllFunc.LoadMenuActivity("text")` Anyway, that functions does absolutely nothing with that string besides returning it unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, you didn't specify an argument when calling LoadMenuActivity. You have to call LoadMenuActivity("Some string").

Answer (score 0):

The argument inside the `()` is requiring a string to be passed to it. Plus that function needs to be a Shared function to call it that way.

```
Literal2.Text = AllFunc.LoadMenuActivity("some string here")
```